# How to rename a wordpress site from http://myserver.example.com/blog to http://myserver.example.com/somethingelse or just http://myserver.example.com

Tags: apache, site-url

I've followed https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-wordpress to install and configure wordpress on an Ubuntu 20.04 machine.  I can access the example site at .../blog and administer it at from .../blog/wp-admin as expected.

How do I change it so that instead of being available at .../blog it is available at either .../somethingelse or just http://myserver.example.com ?

I'd have expected https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-the-site-url/ to be helpful but it isn't especially - if I change the "Site Address (URL)" and "WordPress Address (URL)" fields the site no longer functions.  I would expect I'd need to change /etc/apache2/sites-available/wordpress.conf so that the "Alias" line in there doesn't refer to "/blog" any more, but there's no mention of that at https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-the-site-url/ .  Similarly there's no reference to /etc/wordpress/config-myserver.example.com.php , although this is presumably the "wp-config.php" that https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-the-site-url/ refers to.

I'm guessing that Ubuntu (or Debian) have repackaged wordpress so that things are not quite in the same places as they might be on another OS.  What exactly do I need to do, button by button, to change .../blog to .../somethingelse ?  Obviously, I'm looking for instructions that will work on Ubuntu 20.04 here.

Comment: You should just be able to change the DocumentRoot to point to /usr/share/wordpress, although you might have to do that in the main httpd.conf or a virtual host directive - I don't know how Ubuntu sets up its Apache config.

Answer (score 0):

Those instructions are a little odd to my eye.

I think you're being forced to use `/blog` because of [Step 3](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-wordpress#3-configure-apache-for-wordpress) in the instructions. The Apache directive

```
Alias /blog /usr/share/wordpress
```

...directs Apache to route any requests to `/blog` to the directory where you've installed WordPress. (See Apache's docs on the [`Alias`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) directive.)

I don't know for sure that you'll be able to set your site's root URL (`/`) to load WordPress, but you should easily be able to use `/someotherurl` instead. Just modify the `/etc/apache2/sites-available/wordpress.conf` file and change

```
Alias /blog /usr/share/wordpress
```

to

```
Alias /someotherurl /usr/share/wordpress
```

You'll need to reload the Apache service for this to take effect, using `sudo service apache2 reload` as stated at the end of Step 3.

Comment: Thanks - that's at least half way there!

If I edit /etc/apache2/sites-available/wordpress.conf
so that it reads
Alias /someotherurl /usr/share/wordpress

sudo service apache2 reload

Then
http://myserver.example.com/someotherurl
says "Oops! That page can’t be found."
A link on that page "UbuntuVM66 Wordpress" goes to http://myserver.example.com/blog/
But Apache unsurprisingly says "Not Found" to that URL.

Comment: However, if I change it back and go to
http://myserver.example.com/blog/wp-admin/options-general.php
Both "WordPress Address (URL)" and "Site Address (URL)" are set to "http://myserver.example.com/blog".  So I changed those entries to http://myserver.example.com/someotherurl and clicked apply

The browser redirects to
http://myserver.example.com/someotherurl/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fmyserver.example.com%2Fblog%2Fwp-admin%2Foptions-general.php%3Fsettings-updated%3Dtrue&reauth=1
which says "Not Found"

Comment: So at this point also edit the "Alias" line in the wordpress.conf to
Alias /someotherurl /usr/share/wordpress
and
sudo service apache2 reload

http://myserver.example.com/someotherurl/
now works OK
and so does
http://myserver.example.com/someotherurl/wp-admin

Comment: If I repeat that process with "Alias / /usr/share/wordpress" in the wordpress.conf, and "DocumentRoot /usr/share/wordpress" (as suggested above) in the /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf file, I get an error 403 and Apache's error.log has a line with "AH01276: Cannot serve directory /usr/share/wordpress: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.php) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive" in it - but there's more for me to look at there, obviously.